# Why is emacs swallowing C-)?

Tags: windows, emacs

Running emacs 23.1.50.1 under windows.  Even if I run "emacs -q" to prevent any customizations from my .emacs file, it's swallowing the C-) (that's control + shift + the 0 key) keyboard combination.  This combination doesn't even appear in the "view-lossage" history of keystrokes.

Anyone know how to work around this?  This combination is bound by default in paredit-mode, but I can't use it.

Comment: If it doesn't appear in `view-lossage`, it's probably the OS swallowing the key (or a third-party application that's set it up as a shortcut).

Comment: feed hungry emacs before they are really hungry, otherwise they will swallow _everything_ :)

Answer (score 1):

This is caused by a Windows IME (Input Method Editor) keybinding.  There is info at http://support.microsoft.com/kb/967893 describing how to disable the IME keybinding and thus expose "C-)" to applications, such as Emacs.